# Sticky select box with while loop

Tags: php, webforms

I can't seem to get this right. I am trying to make a select box that gets it values from the database sticky please see my code below :

```
<select name="cob_bank">
   <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
        if($row['Id']==$myId)  {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['Id'].'"selected="selected">'.$row['Name'].'</option>';
        } else {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['Id'].'">'.$row['Name'].'</option>';
        }
    }?>
</select>
```

after the select box is filled in and the submit button is pressed where I save my Post variable

```
$myId = $_POST['cob_name'];
```

The above code does not work I please assist

Comment: you did not show us full code here ..  have you created form tag with name attribute ? it should be in post method. make sure your select box has name attribute with the same name you specified cob_name.

Comment: Please format your code properly, and "does not work" is very broad

Comment: and try print_r($_REQUEST);

Comment: All the code HTML is fine it returns the values correctly, its just that the select box is not sticky once I submit its starts from the first entry and not the value I selected

Comment: please post your **select** tag code

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

the no space could be causing the problem as a space before selected

```
if($row['Id']==$myId)  {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['Id'].'" selected="selected">'.$row['Name'].'</option>';
    }
```

The select name should be set as:

```
<select name='cob_name'>
```

Comment: I have tried it with the space still the same the select box is still not stiky

Comment: have you tried adding $myId to your options so you can verify it contains what you think it does?

Comment: the $myid is set the row['id'] is compared to the $myid in the if clause

Comment: yes but it's not working so are you certain is contains a matching id you can add it to the select option to see it temporarily '.$row['Name'].' - '.$myId.' I suspect it's not matching any of the ids

Comment: the variable is linked to the ID and not the name is the if statement logic behind it correct ?

Comment: the logic seems fine, yes it's linked the id, I'm only suggesting putting it there just to see what it contains it could be that the id is not actually getting added to $myId